# NodeJs API for web scraping using Selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I would like to know if it is possible to create an API in Nodejs to make a long web scraping operation using Selenium. I ask because the operation is so long that, when deploying to Heroku, I am getting a timeout error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from the fact that Heroku routers terminate requests that take longer than 30 seconds as mentioned in their documentation:

> Occasionally a web request may hang or take an excessive amount of time to process by your application. When this happens the router will terminate the request if it takes longer than 30 seconds to complete.

You can use different approaches to solve this issue. I would recommend you either go through their documentation (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout) or use web sockets to transmit data from the server-side to the client-side (However, I tend to avoid using WebSockets for APIs as they are hard to scale).